# Python 3.5 scraper only running the first website off of a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently writing this code to grab restaurants' official website links off from their Yelp pages. The code works mostly, but it returns the first link twice instead of going through the list and returning each item once. I tried to work it out but I'm just stuck on what is causing this to happen. Can you spot what I am doing wrong?

I also have another question about grabbing links from Yelp. I know Yelp may not like it, but I really cannot copy and paste links from 20,000 pages by hand so I have to use this.

Would they block my IP? Will inserting 2-second delays between requests keep them from blocking me? Are there any other ways besides inserting delays?

```
import urllib  
import urllib.request  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

url=[  
"https://www.yelp.com/biz/buffalo-wild-wings-ann-arbor-3",  
"https://www.yelp.com/biz/good-burger-east-dearborn-dearborn?osq=mac+donalds"  
]  

def make_soup(url):  
    for i in url:  
        thepage=urllib.request.urlopen(i)  
        soupdata=BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")  
        return soupdata  

compoundfinal=''  
soup=make_soup(url)  

for i in url:  
    for thing1 in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'mapbox-text'}):  
        for thing2 in thing1.findAll('a',{'rel':'nofollow'}):  
            final='"http://www.'+thing2.text+'",\n'  
            compoundfinal=compoundfinal+final  

print(compoundfinal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to split your processing between two different loops, but not properly saving the data and then re-iterating over it between the two.  You also look like you have the wrong indentation on the return statement in the function definition, so the function returns after the first iteration regardless of the number of items in the list. The below seems to work by placing all the processing into one function.  It was the best way to get working code from your example, however it isn't the best way to tackle the problem.  You would be better off defining your function to process one page, then looping over `url` to call the function.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url=[
"https://www.yelp.com/biz/buffalo-wild-wings-ann-arbor-3",
"https://www.yelp.com/biz/good-burger-east-dearborn-dearborn?osq=mac+donalds"
]

def make_soup(url):
    compoundfinal = ""
    for i in url:
        thepage=urllib.request.urlopen(i)
        soupdata=BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
        for thing1 in soupdata.findAll('div',{'class':'mapbox-text'}):
            for thing2 in thing1.findAll('a',{'rel':'nofollow'}):
                final='"http://www.'+thing2.text+'",\n'
                compoundfinal=compoundfinal+final
    return compoundfinal


final = make_soup(url)

print( final )
```

output

```
"http://www.buffalowildwings.com",
"http://www.goodburgerrestaurant.com"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Not only did you help me solve this specific issue, I also learned a lot from just this post.

Answer (score 1):

An answer for your secondary question:

Yes, putting a delay between scrapes would be a very good idea. I would say a static 2-second delay may not be enough - consider a random delay between 2 and 5, perhaps.That will make the scrapes seem less deterministic, though you might still get caught based on scrapes per hour. It would be worth writing your script so you can restart it, in case there are problems mid-scrape - you don't want to have to start again from the beginning.

Please also [download Yell's Robots Exclusion File](https://www.yell.com/robots.txt) and check your scraping list against their no-scrape list. I notice they request a 10-second delay for Bing, so consider increasing the delay I suggested above.

You might also want to consider the legal aspects of this. Most sites *want* to be scraped, so they can appear in search engines. However some data aggregators may not have the same enthusiasm: they probably want to be found by search engines, but they don't want to be replaced by competitors. Remember that it costs a lot of money to collect the data in the first place, and they may object to third parties getting a free ride. Thus, if you plan to do this regularly in order to update your own website, I think you might run into either technical or legal obstacles.

You may be tempted to use proxies to hide your scraping traffic, but this carries with it an implicit message that you believe you are doing something wrong. Your scrape target will probably make more efforts to block you in this case, and may be more likely to take legal action against you if they find which website you are republishing the data on.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response outlining both possible issues and still providing solutions. I will explore Yell's Robots Exclusion File before I proceed.

Comment: **You also agree not to, and will not assist, encourage, or enable others to:** *Use any robot, spider, site search/retrieval application, or other automated device, process or means to access, retrieve, scrape, or index any portion of the Site or any Site Content;* Restrictions section 6 iii. https://www.yelp.com/static?country=US&p=tos. There is a python api https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-python

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: good find on the API, much better if James can use that! I am sympathetic to some degree to firms who spend a great deal of resources on collecting valuable data, but I am opposed to the view that a TOU can place arbitrary restrictions on a person who has not explicitly signed it. In general I think such documents are at best a statement of company opinion, and would not be very persuasive in court.

Comment: True but as you mentioned it costs a lot of money to gather, filter and store data so when they supply an api and you choose to not use it and violate their TOS instead I think you might just deserve whatever comes your way.